# What are the all possible device information can be collected with Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have an app and want to collect any possible device information. Even battery level, any bit of information. What can I collect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package for possible information are provider by this package [device_info_plus 3.2.2](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)